# Datatables not loading Correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

Simply the library doesn't load correctly due to this, can't use datatables library
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w25Ki.png
This happens
[enter image description here][1]

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.12.0/datatables.min.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.12.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is you jQuery loaded properly? You might need version jquery-3.5.1

Comment: Yes already tried with cdn also... still same issue!

Comment: please see this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/72737/error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-value-file-js-jquery-datatables-min-js it was posted yesterday. It also contains a solution, but it requires you to patch the unminified library and use it locally.

Comment: It Looks like that's it! Let me check and once I'm sure I'll give you the feedback

Comment: the Solution https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/72737/error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-value-file-js-jquery-datatables-min-js Solved it!

Searched for a while. but it only works on the minified version

Comment: Interesting. I am unable to recreate the problem you show in the question, when I use your approach. DataTables loads correctly - no errors. (Also, the linked solution does not explain _why_ the proposed fix is needed, or how it works.)

Comment: If you check the link you will see that's not just me that is having the same issue, even the publisher website has this problem, the simple change from 3 to 2 solved it... why is needed, cause the plugin is malfunction. Thanks @GrafiCode for the tip!

Comment: "_if you check the link_" - That was the first thing I did, when I read this question. "_even the publisher website has this problem_" - The DataTables website does not have the problem for me, or for the people administering the website (as they say themselves in that same link, "_I'm not seeing any errors on that page._"). I would really not trust that **solution-without-explanation**. But that's just me. And none of that explains why I am not able to recreate the problem you are having, based on the information in the question.

Comment: I've stumbled into this sometime ago. Some clients were able to correctly see websites and others can't. I've made some tests and found out that some of them can't open CDN's Links... On the why? Here's the tricky part, after a simple connection using a VPN, everything works correctly, if you turn that VPN off... suddenly it stops working. Haven't tested on nested libraries but I can look into it.